# websql use select in to get rows from an array

Tags: sql, sqlite, web-sql

in websql we can request a certain row like this:

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM tblSettings where id = ?', [id], function(tx, rs){
    // do stuff with the resultset.
},
function errorHandler(tx, e){
    // do something upon error.
    console.warn('SQL Error: ', e);
});
```

however, I know regular SQL and figured i should be able to request

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM tblSettings where id in (?)', [arr], function(tx, rs){
    // do stuff with the resultset.
},
function errorHandler(tx, e){
    // do something upon error.
    console.warn('SQL Error: ', e);
});
```

but that gives us no results, the result is always empty. if i would remove the `[arr]` into `arr`, then the sql would get a variable amount of parameters, so i figured it should be `[arr]`. otherwise it would require us to add a dynamic amount of question marks (as many as there are id's in the array).

so can anyone see what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

aparently, there is no other solution, than to manually add a question mark for every item in your array.

this is actually in the specs on w3.org

```
var q = "";
for each (var i in labels)
  q += (q == "" ? "" : ", ") + "?";

// later to be used as such:
t.executeSql('SELECT id FROM docs WHERE label IN (' + q + ')', labels, function (t, d) {
  // do stuff with result...
});
```

more info here: http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#introduction (at the end of the introduction)

however, at the moment i created a helper function that creates such a string for me
might be better than the above, might not, i haven't done any performance testing.

this is what i use now

```
var createParamString = function(arr){
  return _(arr).map(function(){ return "?"; }).join(',');
}

// when called like this:
createparamString([1,2,3,4,5]);  // >> returns   ?,?,?,?,?
```

this however makes use of the [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) library we have in our project.

Answer (score 0):

Good answer. It was interesting to read an explanation in the official documentation.

I see this question was answered in 2012. I tried it in Google 37 exactly as it is recommened and this is what I got.

Data on input: (I outlined them with the black pencil)

[image]

Chrome complains:

[image]

So  it accepts as many question signs as many input parameters are given. (Let us pay attention that although  array is passed it's treated as one parameter)

Eventually I came up to this solution:

```
    var activeItemIds = [1,2,3];
    var q = ""; 
    for (var i=0; i< activeItemIds.length; i++) {
        q += '"' + activeItemIds[i] + '", ';
    }        
     q= q.substring(0, q.length - 2); 

     var query = 'SELECT "id" FROM "products" WHERE "id"  IN (' + q + ')';
    _db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql(query, [], function (tx, results1) {
            console.log(results1);
            debugger;

        }, function (a, b) {
            console.warn(a);
            console.warn(b);
        })
    })
```